# Escaping special characters in rails .erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

```
name = "SHE® WOMEN'S RACER FLARE TANK"
```

when i try to use name to inject value into a div's data attribute like

```
<div data-name= <%= name  %> > XYZ </div>
```

The output in the browser is

```
<div data-name="SHE® women's=" racer="" flare="" tank="" >
  XYZ
</div>
```

How can i escape the special characters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`content_tag`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) helper to make custom HTML data attributes:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, "XYZ", data: { name: name }) %>
```

---

**Edit**
To answer your comment, you can pass a block to the content tag with any HTML structure you need. You can also add html options such as `id` or `class`:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, id: "product_#{@product.id}", class: ['product-list-item', col_css, @product.name],
                data: { name: @product.name, hook: "products_list_item", sku: @product.sku, product_id: @product.id }) do %>
  # add any html content you need
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi there some other way coz this example is simple but actual code is complex-
<div id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="product-list-item <%= col_css %> <%= product.product_type %>"
     data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product"
     data-name= <%= product.name  %>
     data-sku= <%= product.sku  %>
     data-product-id= <%= product.id  %>
     data-price= <%=lowest ?  lowest : display_price(variants.first || product)   %> >  

</div>

There are multiple divs inside this div

Comment: Thank you @sovalina

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`tag.div` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag). This helper allow you to write your example

```
<div id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="product-list-item <%= col_css %> <%= product.product_type %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Product"; data-name= <%= product.name %> data-sku= <%= product.sku %> data-product-id= <%= product.id %> data-price= <%=lowest ? lowest : display_price(variants.first || product) %> > 
</div>
```

like the following *and* it takes care of the correct escaping of characters:

```
<%= tag.div(
      id:    dom_id(product),
      class: ['product-list-item', col_css,product.product_type],
      data: { 
        hook:      'products_list_item',
        name:       product.name,
        sku:        product.sku,
        product_id: product.id,
        price:      lowest ? lowest : display_price(variants.first || product)
      },
      itemscope: 'itemscope',
      itemtype: 'schema.org/Product'
    ) %>
```

You might want to consider to move this code into a helper.

The `tag` helper allows nested tags too. Example from [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag):

```
tag.div tag.p('Hello world!')  # => <div><p>Hello world!</p></div>
```